# Are there fixed connectors for gpio?

Tags: arduino-uno, mechanical

Curently I am using these connectors for my prototype:
[Ebay link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/120pcs-10cm-2-54mm-1pin-Jumper-Wire-Dupont-Cable-for-Arduino-/381350806379?hash=item58ca47836b:g:V38AAOSwN81WEeMm)

However, I need something more reliable so I can deliver the prototype to a user without to risk that the cables fall out of their pins.
Is there something else to use? I would like to avoid soldering.. :(

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to replace the headers with something else, which means soldering, then you will be soldering.

The options are:

1. Solder different connectors in the place of the existing headers
2. Remove the existing headers and solder wires directly in their place
3. Get a prototyping shield and solder wires in to that
4. Get a prototyping shield and solder different connectors to it.

Whatever you choose you will be soldering.

Don't be scared of soldering - it's the most basic thing you need to be able to do when you are working with electronics.

Answer (score 0):

The cables you link are supposed to be assembled by *crimping* rather the *soldering*.  The risk of them falling out is mostly because the housing are only for a single contact.

If you instead get multi-contact housings the width of the headers you are matching, and insert contacts into those in the desired positions, the risk of things falling out will be greatly reduced.  You can add a label to indicate correct insertion direction.

Of course, a much better result would be to make either a custom shield with terminations for the signals you need to route elsewhere, or to replace the Arduino itself with a custom ATmega board that handles application-appropriate polarity-keyed wiring harnesses.